# Google cloud Storage Error - File write

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I tried to pull the report from Double Click Search API and put it into Google Cloud Storage by using google app engine(Python).

The following code is used to pull the report and place in google cloud storage.

Code:

```
def download_files(service, report_id, report_fragment):
  """Generate and print sample report.

  Args:
    service: An authorized Doublelcicksearch service.
    report_id: The ID DS has assigned to a report.
    report_fragment: The 0-based index of the file fragment from the files array.
  """
  print "Enter into download_files", report_id
  filename="/awstogcs/DoubleClickSearch_Campaign"+report_id+"_"+report_fragment+".csv"
  write_retry_params = _gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
  gcs_file=_gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type='text/plain',retry_params=write_retry_params)
  request = service.reports().getFile(reportId=report_id, reportFragment=report_fragment)
  time.sleep(120)
  gcs_file.write(request.execute())
  gcs_file.close()
```

Not sure why getting this error message.

Error Message:

```
INFO     2017-06-26 13:23:37,417 module.py:809] default: "PUT /_ah/gcs/awstogcs/DoubleClickSearch_CampaignAAAndQT-U9IDyFYX_0.csv?upload_id=encoded_gs_file%3AYXdzdG9nY3MvRG91YmxlQ2xpY2tTZWFyY2hfQ2FtcGFpZ25BQUFuZFFULVU5SUR5RllYXzAuY3N2 HTTP/1.1" 308 -
INFO     2017-06-26 13:23:37,710 module.py:809] default: "PUT /_ah/gcs/awstogcs/DoubleClickSearch_CampaignAAAndQT-U9IDyFYX_0.csv?upload_id=encoded_gs_file%3AYXdzdG9nY3MvRG91YmxlQ2xpY2tTZWFyY2hfQ2FtcGFpZ25BQUFuZFFULVU5SUR5RllYXzAuY3N2 HTTP/1.1" 308 -
INFO     2017-06-26 13:23:37,976 module.py:809] default: "PUT /_ah/gcs/awstogcs/DoubleClickSearch_CampaignAAAndQT-U9IDyFYX_0.csv?upload_id=encoded_gs_file%3AYXdzdG9nY3MvRG91YmxlQ2xpY2tTZWFyY2hfQ2FtcGFpZ25BQUFuZFFULVU5SUR5RllYXzAuY3N2 HTTP/1.1" 308 -
INFO     2017-06-26 13:23:38,157 module.py:809] default: "PUT /_ah/gcs/awstogcs/DoubleClickSearch_CampaignAAAndQT-U9IDyFYX_0.csv?upload_id=encoded_gs_file%3AYXdzdG9nY3MvRG91YmxlQ2xpY2tTZWFyY2hfQ2FtcGFpZ25BQUFuZFFULVU5SUR5RllYXzAuY3N2 HTTP/1.1" 308 -
INFO     2017-06-26 13:23:38,440 module.py:809] default: "PUT /_ah/gcs/awstogcs/DoubleClickSearch_CampaignAAAndQT-U9IDyFYX_0.csv?upload_id=encoded_gs_file%3AYXdzdG9nY3MvRG91YmxlQ2xpY2tTZWFyY2hfQ2FtcGFpZ25BQUFuZFFULVU5SUR5RllYXzAuY3N2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but it could be because App Engine does not give access to file system. So your file was never written to the machine from which you were trying to copy it to Bucket. You can easily confirm if the file is being written/downloaded on the machine.

Comment: I try to copy the file directly to cloud storage, not writing to file system. Some times it is running but most of the times I was getting the above error.

Comment: It may relate to [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) (note that a 308 status is not an error)

Comment: Thanks snakecharmerb. Please let me know how to handle this.